# When converting string to 2d array, first element gets corrupt

Tags: c, malloc, heap-corruption

When converting a given string to a 2D array, the first element of the array gets changed to a random string every time I try to return.

Here is the code. I've GDBed and tried with no-key strings and it still fails. `count_letters` and `count_words` just loop through the given pointer until they find a key or to count all keys, respectively.

```
char **str_to_dp(char const *str, char const key)
{
    char **arr = malloc(sizeof(*arr) * (count_words(str, key) + 1));
    int i = 0;

    if (!arr)
        perror("get_PATH");
    for (int j = 0, word = 0; str[j]; j++, i++, word = 0) {
        while (str[j] == key)
            j++;
        arr[i] = malloc(count_letters(str + j, key) * sizeof(char));
        if (!arr[i])
            perror("get_PATH");
        while (str[j] != key)
            arr[i][word++] = str[j++];
    }
    arr[i] = 0;
    return arr;
}
```

When printing `arr[i]` inside the loop and when GDB-ing still inside the loop, the first element remains OK. Whenever I try to print (say, with a loop right before return), I get random values for the first row (and sometimes second, if the string has enough elements). Any idea why?

Thanks for reading through.

Answer (score 0):

Try single stepping it in gdb.  The basic issue is that whenever you reach the bottom of your for loop `str[j] == key` will be true.  Unless key is `'\0'` the test `str[j]` will always succeed and your for loop will walk off the end of the array.

You need to either count the words in the for loop rather than running till `str[j] == 0` or change the `while` loop at the end of the for loop to have `while (str[j] != key && str[j])` as its test.

Comment: Thanks, I figured it out by chance (`grep -R '(char' .`). The case in point begins and ends with `key` (usually just ";"), but your remark was useful.

Answer (score 0):

Besides what @dgnuff said, it seems my problem was outside the function. I had cast the `(char **)` array to `(char const *)` instead of `(char const **)`.